# Moving Partitioning Files To Another Disk Drive In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, migration

There is a production table which was partitioned by someone in our company. Some partitioning files was wrongly located to different disk drive.

I have to move those files to the disk where they have to be. Those partitioned files for 2020 and 2021 are on production. How can I move those files to the main disk drive without stopping the database or services?

Comment: The files should be empty so just drop them and add the new ones to the place you want.

Comment: As far as i know, there was some data on those files. Is there a way to save the data before dropping them? @DenisRubashkin

Comment: If there is some data inside  a database file, that file can't be dropped. If you tried you would get an error ( I wouldn't try to check it out on the production though ). Anyway, you can add a new file to the filegroup and then use a command `DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'OldFileLogicalName' , EMPTYFILE)` to move data from the old file.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Thank you very much for the help and informations you shared with me. Will this command " DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'OldFileLogicalName' , EMPTYFILE) " move the data new logical file? If so, where should i define the destination logical filename in the command?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move a data file, if you don't have a maintain window, you should perform several steps:

Add a new file to the filegroup ([Add Data or Log Files to a
   Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/add-data-or-log-files-to-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName]
ADD FILE ( 
      NAME = N'NewFileLogicalName'
    , FILENAME = N'C:\Data\NewFileName.ndf'
    , SIZE = 8MB
    , FILEGROWTH = 128MB 
) TO FILEGROUP [YourFilegroupName];
```

Empty the old file ([DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'OldFileLogicalName' , EMPTYFILE);
```

Remove the old file ([Delete Data or Log Files from a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/delete-data-or-log-files-from-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName]
REMOVE FILE OldFileLogicalName;
```

If a logical name matters ([ALTER DATABASE File and Filegroup Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName]
MODIFY FILE (
    NAME = N'NewFileLogicalName'
    , NEWNAME = N'OldFileLogicalName'
);
```